# Are there any drawbacks to using cascading "else if" statements?

Tags: c, if-statement, curly-brackets

This question pertains to pretty much all C-like "curly bracket" programming languages.

I'm talking about using the following:

```c
if(condition)
    meh();
else if(condition1)
    bleh();
else if(condition2)
    moo();
else
    foo();
```

Are there any caveats to be aware of when using this idiom in code? I'm looking for things like performance penalties, compiler limits, etc. What would a typical compiler do with something like this?

I ask because even though it looks nice and flat to the human eye, it would actually be strictly parsed as equivalent to the following, with the braces added:

```c
if(condition)
{
     meh();
}
else
{
    if(condition1)
    {
        bleh();
    }
    else
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

i.e. the `else if` is not really a delimiter; instead each `if` would be nested inside the preceding `else`. It would be like parsing x+y+z+... as x+(y+(z+...)).

Do compilers actually treat it this way, or would they treat `else if` as a special case? If the former, what caveats would I have to be aware of?

(This is my first question on StackOverflow.)

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is really just a comment, while it's important to be aware of these things, I would concentrate my efforts on my algorithm and data structures and generating readable code, and leave optimization issues to the compiler (assuming no gross coding errors that introduce inefficiencies).

Comment: This is one of those things where you need to realize that the compiler is smarter than you are where optimization of small segments of code are concerned (provided you're not doing something ludicrous), and that your job is to a) feed the compiler better algorithms, which are b) kept as human-readable as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the variant with `else-if` wherever possible. This construct does not have disadvantages.

It is true that it is not possible to **guarantee** anything about the compiler optimization. At the same time experience and reasonable thinking both tell that constructs of this complexity is not a problem for modern-days compilers.

Answer (score 2):

When I look at this. I think this in my head as far as optimizations are concerned;

```
if(blah)
  //Most likely code to be run.
elseif(bleh)
  //Less likely code to be run.
elseif(blarg)
  //Even less likely to be run.
else
  //Almost never ever gets here.
```

Depending on what your evaluating, a switch statement might be better.

Answer (score 1):

The two constructions are entirely identical as far as the language is concerned. Compilers are free to create any type of machine code that creates the mandated behaviour, and in all likelihood an optimizing compiler will treat both versions in the exact same way.

If it wants to, the compiler can even replace repeated conditionals by a jump table. Again, it shouldn't matter how your code whether or not such an implementation is used. (If you're really curious, just compile and compare the assembly.)

Write the code in a way that makes its structure the most obvious and clear possible. If all branches are on equal footing, I'd personally prefer `else if`s, or even a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing some experiments with the following simple code to find out what compiler does when it optimizes a `if-else` structure. The code i'm using is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                if(arr[i] == 1)
                        printf("one\n");
                else if (arr[i] == 2)
                        printf("two\n");
                else if (arr[i] = 3)
                        printf("three\n");
                else printf("blah\n");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Surely its not very good example. As there is nothing dynamic here to distinguish **likely** and **unlikely** brunch.

But to my surprise the code it generated is vastly different.

First without any optimization i have :

```
   0x0000000000400506 <+66>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
   0x0000000000400509 <+69>:    cdqe   
   0x000000000040050b <+71>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp+rax*4-0x20]
   0x000000000040050f <+75>:    cmp    eax,0x1
   0x0000000000400512 <+78>:    jne    0x400520 <main+92>
   0x0000000000400514 <+80>:    mov    edi,0x400668
   0x0000000000400519 <+85>:    call   0x4003b8 <puts@plt>
   0x000000000040051e <+90>:    jmp    0x400551 <main+141>
   0x0000000000400520 <+92>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
   0x0000000000400523 <+95>:    cdqe   
   0x0000000000400525 <+97>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp+rax*4-0x20]
   0x0000000000400529 <+101>:   cmp    eax,0x2
   0x000000000040052c <+104>:   jne    0x40053a <main+118>
   0x000000000040052e <+106>:   mov    edi,0x40066c
   0x0000000000400533 <+111>:   call   0x4003b8 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000400538 <+116>:   jmp    0x400551 <main+141>
   0x000000000040053a <+118>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
   0x000000000040053d <+121>:   cdqe   
   0x000000000040053f <+123>:   mov    DWORD PTR [rbp+rax*4-0x20],0x3
   0x0000000000400547 <+131>:   mov    edi,0x400670
   0x000000000040054c <+136>:   call   0x4003b8 <puts@plt>
```

The code is pretty straight forward. sequential `cmp` and `jne` is the heart of the `if-else` structure as expected.

But the fun begins with (`-O3`)

```
0x0000000000400510 <+64>:   call   0x4003b8 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000400515 <+69>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rsp+0x4]
   0x0000000000400519 <+73>:    cmp    eax,0x1
   0x000000000040051c <+76>:    je     0x400640 <main+368>
   0x0000000000400522 <+82>:    cmp    eax,0x2
   0x0000000000400525 <+85>:    je     0x4005a0 <main+208>
   0x0000000000400527 <+87>:    mov    edi,0x40074c
   0x000000000040052c <+92>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rsp+0x4],0x3
   0x0000000000400534 <+100>:   call   0x4003b8 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000400539 <+105>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rsp+0x8]
   0x000000000040053d <+109>:   cmp    eax,0x1
   0x0000000000400540 <+112>:   je     0x4005b3 <main+227>
   0x0000000000400542 <+114>:   cmp    eax,0x2
   0x0000000000400545 <+117>:   je     0x400630 <main+352>
   0x000000000040054b <+123>:   mov    edi,0x40074c
   0x0000000000400550 <+128>:   mov    DWORD PTR [rsp+0x8],0x3
   0x0000000000400558 <+136>:   call   0x4003b8 <puts@plt>
   0x000000000040055d <+141>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rsp+0xc]
   0x0000000000400561 <+145>:   cmp    eax,0x1
   0x0000000000400564 <+148>:   je     0x4005d0 <main+256>
   0x0000000000400566 <+150>:   cmp    eax,0x2
   0x0000000000400569 <+153>:   je     0x400618 <main+328>
   0x000000000040056f <+159>:   mov    edi,0x40074c
   0x0000000000400574 <+164>:   mov    DWORD PTR [rsp+0xc],0x3
   0x000000000040057c <+172>:   call   0x4003b8 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000400581 <+177>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rsp+0x10]
   0x0000000000400585 <+181>:   cmp    eax,0x1
   0x0000000000400588 <+184>:   je     0x4005e8 <main+280>
   0x000000000040058a <+186>:   cmp    eax,0x2
   0x000000000040058d <+189>:   je     0x400600 <main+304>
   0x000000000040058f <+191>:   mov    edi,0x40074c
   0x0000000000400594 <+196>:   call   0x4003b8 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000400599 <+201>:   xor    eax,eax
   0x000000000040059b <+203>:   add    rsp,0x28
   0x000000000040059f <+207>:   ret    
   0x00000000004005a0 <+208>:   mov    edi,0x400752
   0x00000000004005a5 <+213>:   call   0x4003b8 <puts@plt>
   0x00000000004005aa <+218>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rsp+0x8]
   0x00000000004005ae <+222>:   cmp    eax,0x1
   0x00000000004005b1 <+225>:   jne    0x400542 <main+114>
   0x00000000004005b3 <+227>:   mov    edi,0x400748
   0x00000000004005b8 <+232>:   call   0x4003b8 <puts@plt>
   0x00000000004005bd <+237>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rsp+0xc]
   0x00000000004005c1 <+241>:   cmp    eax,0x1
   0x00000000004005c4 <+244>:   jne    0x400566 <main+150>
   0x00000000004005c6 <+246>:   nop    WORD PTR cs:[rax+rax*1+0x0]
   0x00000000004005d0 <+256>:   mov    edi,0x400748
   0x00000000004005d5 <+261>:   call   0x4003b8 <puts@plt>
   0x00000000004005da <+266>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rsp+0x10]
   0x00000000004005de <+270>:   cmp    eax,0x1
   0x00000000004005e1 <+273>:   jne    0x40058a <main+186>
   0x00000000004005e3 <+275>:   nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
   0x00000000004005e8 <+280>:   mov    edi,0x400748
   0x00000000004005ed <+285>:   call   0x4003b8 <puts@plt>
   0x00000000004005f2 <+290>:   xor    eax,eax
   0x00000000004005f4 <+292>:   add    rsp,0x28
   0x00000000004005f8 <+296>:   ret    
   0x00000000004005f9 <+297>:   nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
   0x0000000000400600 <+304>:   mov    edi,0x400752
   0x0000000000400605 <+309>:   call   0x4003b8 <puts@plt>
   0x000000000040060a <+314>:   xor    eax,eax
   0x000000000040060c <+316>:   add    rsp,0x28
   0x0000000000400610 <+320>:   ret    
   0x0000000000400611 <+321>:   nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
   0x0000000000400618 <+328>:   mov    edi,0x400752
   0x000000000040061d <+333>:   call   0x4003b8 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000400622 <+338>:   jmp    0x400581 <main+177>
   0x0000000000400627 <+343>:   nop    WORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
   0x0000000000400630 <+352>:   mov    edi,0x400752
   0x0000000000400635 <+357>:   call   0x4003b8 <puts@plt>
   0x000000000040063a <+362>:   jmp    0x40055d <main+141>
   0x000000000040063f <+367>:   nop
   0x0000000000400640 <+368>:   mov    edi,0x400748
   0x0000000000400645 <+373>:   call   0x4003b8 <puts@plt>
   0x000000000040064a <+378>:   jmp    0x400539 <main+105>
```

Important thing to note here :

1. A lot of unconditional jumps to move around the code.
2. Using `je` instead of `jne`.
3. There are lot of duplicated code regions. comparison with `1` is done multiple times.

I will dig into the optimized assembler more and keep this post updated for any interesting find. This is not so much of answer, but an investigation and also invitation for others to do similar kind of investigation to find out important optimization practices.

EDIT:

Compiler info :

```
[root@s1 ~]# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)
```

Optimization info :

-O2 turns on the following optimization flags :

```
-fthread-jumps 
  -falign-functions  -falign-jumps 
  -falign-loops  -falign-labels 
  -fcaller-saves 
  -fcrossjumping 
  -fcse-follow-jumps  -fcse-skip-blocks 
  -fdelete-null-pointer-checks 
  -fdevirtualize 
  -fexpensive-optimizations 
  -fgcse  -fgcse-lm  
  -fhoist-adjacent-loads 
  -finline-small-functions 
  -findirect-inlining 
  -fipa-sra 
  -foptimize-sibling-calls 
  -fpartial-inlining 
  -fpeephole2 
  -fregmove 
  -freorder-blocks  -freorder-functions 
  -frerun-cse-after-loop  
  -fsched-interblock  -fsched-spec 
  -fschedule-insns  -fschedule-insns2 
  -fstrict-aliasing -fstrict-overflow 
  -ftree-switch-conversion -ftree-tail-merge 
  -ftree-pre 
  -ftree-vrp
```

-O3 will add additional optimization with -O2 :

```
-finline-functions, -funswitch-loops, -fpredictive-commoning, -fgcse-after-reload, -ftree-vectorize, -fvect-cost-model, -ftree-partial-pre and -fipa-cp-clone
```

`if-else` block related optimizations :

> -fcse-follow-jumps
>       In common subexpression elimination (CSE), scan through jump instructions when the target of the jump is not reached by any other
>   path. For example, when CSE encounters an if statement with an else
>   clause, CSE follows the jump when the condition tested is false.
>
> -fcse-skip-blocks
>       This is similar to -fcse-follow-jumps, but causes CSE to follow jumps that conditionally skip over blocks. When CSE encounters a
>   simple if statement with no else clause, -fcse-skip-blocks causes CSE
>   to follow the jump around the body of the if.
>
> fhoist-adjacent-loads
>       Speculatively hoist loads from both branches of an if-then-else if the loads are from adjacent locations in the same structure and the
>   target architecture has a conditional move instruction. This flag is
>   enabled by default at -O2 and higher.

Comment: What compiler are you using? I did a similar experiment in Visual C++ 2010 and, while I do know some x86, I didn't have the patience to go through all those `jxx`s.